# Method to pass only accepted parameter values

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

Assuming the following method:

```
int ExtractMedian(int Statistic)
{
    return ExtractionWork;
}
```

Is it possible to force `Statistic` to accept only odd numbers like `1, 3, 5` by using `ref` for example but without checking the value after it is passed?

Comment: I don't see how would ref help in this situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "force"? What do you want to happen if the consumer passed an even number?

Comment: Well, by using `ref`, the called method is reflected in the calling method, so what i actually meant by "for example", is a way similar to passing a `ref parameter`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Something like an invalid method trying to pass an invalid parameter kind of.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you want an exception to be thrown or do you want a compilation error, or what exactly?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Exactly a compilation error what i meant.

Comment: @Ch344y that would require you to know all inputs to `ExtractMedian` at compile time, can you guarantee that?

Comment: What if the argument value is not a constant? E.g., what if the argument value comes from the user?

Comment: Hmm.. that all make sense.

Comment: I don't think you can do that at compile time at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to force `Statistic` to accept only odd numbers like `1, 3, 5` 
>   by using `ref` for example but without checking the value after it is passed?

No, I don't think so.

I would simply check at the start of the method:

```
int ExtractMedian(int Statistic)
{
    if(Statistic % 2 == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Statistic must be odd");

    return ExtractionWork;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that.

Code Contracts COULD be used to force this - but they are basically a post processing step in code that then can get used by an analyzer to see an invalid call. They are NOT part of the integral .NET functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do the odd or even check somewhere, and it is usually better practice making it the responsibility of the function to check its input is valid.

Having said that, if this isn't an option, you could make an Odd class, whose values can only be odd numbers.

```
public class odd {
  int value;
  int get {return value;}
  void set{//check if odd before setting value;}
}
```

Comment: if anything, I would suggest an immutable struct containing an int value.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but why immutable?

Comment: Here is the [short answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil). For the long answer you might also want to [read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751911/why-are-c-sharp-structs-immutable)

Answer (score 0):

you can declare argument as a class that has an implicit conversion from int and check value in the class.

```
public class OddValue  
{  
    private int _value = 1;  
    public int Value  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return _value;  
        }  

        set
        {  
            if (value % 2 == 0)  
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();  
            _value = value;  
        }  
    }  

    public OddValue(int value)  
    {  
        this.Value = value;  
    }  
public static implicit operator OddValue(int value)  
    {  
        return new OddValue(value);  
    }  
}  

public static void test(OddValue value)  
    {  

    }  

test(5);
```