# cannot implicitly convert type int' to unityengine.vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hi i am new in unity so this my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        var pos = transform.position;
        pos.x += 1;
        transform.position = pos;
        string ss = "hellow";

        if(pos>100){
            print (ss);
        }
    }
}
```

but give me this error in if condition line :cannot implicitly convert type int' to unityengine.vector3'

Comment: Well yes - what do you expect `pos > 100` to mean? `pos` is a position, a `Vector3`... what does it mean for a position to be greater than 100?

Comment: `try this: `if (pos.x > 100) {...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

transform.position is of type Vector3. you should instead do pos.x > 100 instead of pos > 100 inside the if condition.

Answer (score 2):

You made two errors, here.

At first, you cannot modify a value for a single axis at a time, in C#. You have to reassign the entire vector.

So, `pos.x += 1;` is wrong and it should be:

```
pos = new Vector3(pos.x + 1, pos.y, pos.z);
```

In the end, also the test `if(pos>100){` is wrong: you should take a particular axis' value to check (I think:  `if(pos.x>100){`).

Comment: i just use pos.x += 1 and my code work fine . so can u tell me what is vectror3 or vector1,vector2 !?

Comment: `pos.x += 1;` is totally fine

Comment: in general immutability aids in reasoning about code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751911/why-are-c-sharp-structs-immutable

Comment: admittedly it can all seem a bit academic until you see the benefits in use