# c# how to convert array of struct to struct of array

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, struct

I'm starting with an IntPtr to structured data from a hardware source that sends periodic packets.  A thread copies a packet from the Intptr buffer and places byte[] into a queue.  Later the queue is read and byte[] is converted to a structure using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871/reading-a-c-c-data-structure-in-c-sharp-from-a-byte-array/2887#2887) and becomes a collection (array) of type Packet.

```
struct Packet {
  long time;
  int field1;
  short field2;
}

Packet[] array_of_packet;
```

**Without duplicating the structure definition,** I would like to *use* the data as if it was a structure of arrays.

```
struct ArrayOfPacket {
  long[] time;
  int[] field1;
  short[] field2;
}

ArrayOfPacket data;
```

This format allows other functions use them as vectors:

```
Plot(data.time, data.field1);
```

Comment: I lost! Anyways, it should be long[] time and not long time[]

Comment: Well, that's a completely different layout. You'll need to copy everything over manually, item by item.

Comment: You really should look into creating [immutable structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751911/why-are-c-sharp-structs-immutable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is an easy way to transform to arrays, then just use LINQ:

```
Plot (array_of_packet.Select(p => p.time).ToArray(),
      array_of_packet.Select(p => p.field1).ToArray());
```

If you're looking for a magic way to rearrange the data in memory without the cost of copying, then you're out of luck. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy with Linq

```
data.time = array_of_packet.Select(p => p.time).ToArray();
data.field1 = array_of_packet.Select(p => p.field1).ToArray();
data.field2 = array_of_packet.Select(p => p.field2).ToArray();
```

Though you'll need to make the properties `public`

A more effecient solution might be

```
var time = new long[array_of_packet.Length];
var field1 = new int[array_of_packet.Length];
var field2 = new short[array_of_packet.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < array_of_packet.Length; i++)
{
    time[i] = array_of_paket[i].time;
    field1[i] = array_of_paket[i].field1;
    field2[i] = array_of_paket[i].field2;
}

data.time = time;
data.field1 = field1;
data.field2 = field2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class that exposes an array-like accessor syntax:

```
class ArrayWrapper<T, TField>
{
    Func<T, TField> getField;
    T[] array;

    public ArrayWrapper(T[] array, Func<T, TField> getField)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.getField = getField;
    }

    public TField this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.getField(this.array[index]);}
    }

}
```

Then, with a simple helper method like this:

```
ArrayWrapper<T, TField> Wrap<T, TField>(T[] array, Func<T, TField> getField)
{
    return new ArrayWrapper<T, TField>(array, getField);
}
```

You could create an object like this:

```
var data = new
{
    time = Wrap(array_of_packet, p => p.time),
    field1 = Wrap(array_of_packet, p => p.field1),
    field2 = Wrap(array_of_packet, p => p.field2)
};
```

... which could be used the way you want:

```
Plot(data.time, data.field1);
```

Depending on your specific needs, you could elaborate on this in a number of ways:

- Make the class implement an interface like `IList<TField>` so that `Plot()` can be written in a way that's agnostic of the underlying type. (Arrays already implement `IList<TField>`.)
- If performance is a high priority, rather than using a delegate (`Func<,>`), you could add `where T is struct` to the `ArrayWrapper` definition, and have the `ArrayWrapper` take a byte offset as its constructor parameter, and do some `unsafe` magic to access the field's data more quickly.

Comment: When I asked the question - this is what I was looking for -

Comment: @brainfog: I thought it might be. I love LINQ, but it sounded like you were trying to avoid copying the data into multiple arrays.

Comment: Initially I was thinking of it in a step-by-step way :  1) collect data 2) convert to struct and an array of them 3) transform to an structure of arrays without re-typing the original structure (since I have many of them and they could change later)