# Deep copy value of dictionary to a variable c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
employeeDict = new Dict<int, Employee>();
```

If I do

```
var employee = dict[1];
```

and then

```
employee.Name = "Changed"
```

It gets affected in the original dictionary too.
What to do if I don't want that to happen?

Comment: There is no built-in deep copy in C#. You have to do it manually. Make a class method that creates a copy of itself.

Comment: @Dialecticus thanks for your reply, check my answer, I tried that and it worked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something like this

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.Id = employeeDict[1].Id;
e.Name = "Changed";
e.Address = employeeDict[1].Address;
```

This also works. Thank you others for your reply.

Comment: This would be 'brittle', i.e. changes to the employee class could easily result in properties not being copied, with undetected bugs as a result.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way to provide a deep copy of arbitrary objects. You need to provide that yourself.

My recommendation would be to avoid cloning and instead embrace immutable types. I.e. make all fields and properties of the class read only. Instead of changing a property you would be forced to create a new object. See [this answer for more details about the benefit of immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753640/12342238).

[Record types in c# 9](http://coolingDegreeDays%20with%20%7B%20BaseTemperature%20=%2041%20%7D) makes this fairly easy, allowing you to write:

```
var employeeWithChangedName = employee with { Name = "Changed"};
```

c# 10 allows the same [with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) syntax to be used for structs and anonymous types.

Comment: In C# 10, you can use [a `with` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) with any structure or anonymous type as well as records.

Comment: @Richard Deeming Thanks! did not notice that had been added in c# 10.

Comment: @JonasH thanks for your reply, check my answer, I tried that and it worked here.